# Using sort within template class (C++)

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to sort my list with the Standard algorithm `std::sort`.

Here is my try:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
class MyList {
private:
    std::list<T> myList;        
public:
    void add(T item) {
        myList.push_back(item);
    }

    void mySort() {
        std::sort(myList.begin(), myList.end());
    }
};
```

**Compile error:**

```
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5475:22: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\src\firstone.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:327:5: note: template<class _Iterator> typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:327:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,
                 from ..\src\mylist.h:5,
                 from ..\src\firstone.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5475:22: note:   'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2);
                      ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\src\firstone.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:384:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:384:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,
                 from ..\src\mylist.h:5,
                 from ..\src\firstone.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5475:22: note:   'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2);
                      ^

18:57:32 Build Finished (took 986ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may use `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to sort a list. Lists don't support random access iterators which are required for the `std::sort` to work. (Lists support only bidirectional iterators.)

In my humble opinion, this is faulty logic coming from the "great gods of C++".

You can use the `list::sort` member function to sort a list.

Comment: Well, the great gods of C++ provide `std::list::sort`. I guess `std::sort` could have been specialized to use that.

Comment: @juanchopanza doesn't matter when writing generic code, I would need to provide a silly specialization for lists (and forward lists for that matter) just because of a silly implementation detail that for some reason made its way to semantics of sorting

Comment: @juanchopanza container concept (or something like sortable which is actually slightly fuzzy) should surely not require a random access iterator

Answer (score 1):

The standard algorithm `std::sort` requires random access iterators,`std::list<>::iterators`  are bidirectional iterators)

Use member function  [`std::list<>::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) to sort the list

Answer (score 1):

`std::list` does not have random access iterators, which is a requirement for `std::sort`. But you can use the [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) member function instead.

Note that this assumes that you need an `std::list` in the first place. In my experience this is rarely the case in real code. It could well be that an `std::vector` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices: either switch to using `std::list`'s `sort()` member function:

```
myList.sort();
```

...or else switch to a different container type such as `vector` or `deque`, that supports `std::sort` by providing random access iterators.

In nearly every possible case, the latter is the correct choice; `std::list` is (in my opinion) nearly always a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use code below:

> ```
>   void mySort() 
>   {
>     myList.sort();
>     //std::sort(myList.begin(), myList.end());
>   }
> ```